# Replacing Unique Constraint with Trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

I need to replace a unique constraint with a trigger, but I found a problem (I'm using DB2).
Let's say I have a table R with a attribute A integer. I defined this trigger (similar for update):

```
CREATE TRIGGER R_A_UNIQUE
BEFORE INSERT ON R
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM R WHERE A = N.A))
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70000' ('ATTRIBUTE A MUST BE UNIQUE');
```

It works in normal cases, but if add multiple rows like that:

```
INSERT INTO R VALUES (4),(4),(4);
```

all values are inserted with no problem!

Am I missing something? Thank you very much

Comment: Why do you "need to replace a unique constraint with a trigger"?

Comment: In DB2 you can't define an attribute as unique if it allows null values

Comment: Try using a unique index instead of a unique constraint.  From what I have read DB2 will allow that (with some workarounds to handle teh NULL values since the unique index treats two NULLs as equal).  See my answer below for an example

Comment: You can avoid this problem if you are using DB2 10.5 for Linux/UNIX/Windows: it allows you to create indexes with `EXCLUDE NULL KEYS`

Comment: I suppose the first question we should be asking is "Why do you think you need a nullable unique key?".  I think a lot of times this shows up when people store the relationship from the wrong side.  Making the other table have the foreign key may cause this to disappear.  Alternatively, creating a cross-ref table (or otherwise extracting the relationship) would also make this go away.  So, what does your table design look like?

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment.

The `insert` is a single transaction.  So, the state of the table does not change during the course of the inserts.  That is, the trigger is called but on the original version of the table, all three times.

This makes it difficult to implement something like a unique constraint inside a trigger, and one that can handle multiple inserts at the same time.  My advice is to stick with the unique constraint and not try to reproduce it in a trigger.

I should add that you might be able to change the semantics of the trigger by using an "after insert" trigger.  However, this would allow the duplicates into the table, and then you would have to delete them afterwards.

Comment: I understand that, but in DB2 you can't define an attribute as unique if it allows null values, so what can I do?

Comment: I don't think you actually need to delete anything in that case if you raise a signal, as the statement will supposedly be rolled back by the application.

Comment: You might be able to do `create unique index . . . exclude NULL keys` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You stated in comments above that the reason for using a trigger instead of unique constraint is that "In DB2 you can't define an attribute as unique if it allows null values".

According to what I have read, DB2 will allow a "unique **index**" on Nullable columns, but will not allow "unique **constraints**" on nullable columns.

Another issue is that DB2 by default will only allow one `NULL` value within a unique index on a single column, and will treat 2 `NULL` values as a violation of the unique index.

You can work around this issue, and still use a unique index, by using Generated columns for the columns that allow `NULL`s, using the pattern mentioned in this article (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/unique_where_not_null_indexes26?lang=en), which states

> What is needed is an extra column that makes all NULL keys unique but
>   does not interfere with uniqueness enforcement if there is any NULL
>   column in the key

Steps:

1) Alter table `R` to add a generated column which will make the `NULL` values be treated as unique within the index.

```
ALTER TABLE R 
ADD A_UNQKEY INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN A IS NULL THEN pk ELSE NULL END))
```

...where `pk` is the primay key of table `r`.  Also note that you may need to change the data type from `INT` to whatever type your primary key is.

2) Create the unique index on both `a` and `a_unqkey` columns.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_R_A ON R(a, a_unqkey);
```

So now, an example of values in table `R`:

```
pk, a, a_unqkey
1, NULL, 1
2, 'value1', NULL
3, 'value2', NULL
4, NULL, 4
```

Without the `a_unqkey` field, your unique index on column `a` would look like this:

```
NULL
'value1'
'value2'
NULL   <<**VIOLATES UNIQUE INDEX b/c DUPLICATE OF NULL FROM ROW 1**
```

However, if you create the unique index on `R(a, a_unqkey)`, then it would use the following values:

```
NULL, 1
'value1', NULL
'value2', NULL
NULL, 4  <<Still unique b/c the other pair is NULL, 1
```